# Is this sentence understandable?

Tags: grammar

> The cubs should be felt loyal by their parents to survive their
>   childhood.

I wrote this sentence, and what I meant to say was that "cubs can survive only if their parents feel that they are loyal." But this sentence seems to be not understandable by many people. Is there something grammatically wrong with it? Or is it just that it's too complicated?

Comment: I can't say I understand what you are saying. Is it that only the cubs whose parents feel those cubs are loyal to the parents themselves will survive? So if the parent does not believe the cub loyal to that parent, that cub will not survive? Notice I've stripped out (almost) all the pronouns to make sure we know who we are talking about here.

Comment: What I was trying to say was that, yes, if the parents of those cubs do not feel that their children  are loyal to them (the parents), it would be hard for the cubs to survive.

Comment: The sentence is confusing, I think it's the word *loyal* that throws most people off. We don't normally associate the feeling of loyalty in animals towards their offspring. It's usual (primal) instinct, bonding, or protection,  And cubs don't have a "childhood", they have "first days / weeks / (e.g) three months or year". baby (mammals) animals have a primal instinct to immediately bond with their mothers, it's inbuilt/hard-wired in their brains. They are usually so helpless, they cannot afford to be independent or ignore their mothers.

Comment: Whereas humans feel loyalty, and their children feel a sense of duty. Of course we attribute "loyalty" to domesticated animals, *dog is man's best friend*, but that is a different kettle of fish! :) Summary: You have picked inappropriate terms to express your meaning.

Answer (score 2):

It's extremely awkward. I would write it as follows:

> Only cubs whose parents feel that they are loyal (to the parents) will survive their childhood.

The sense is slightly different, but the meaning and intent are clearer.

Comment: This is way better... but is my sentence just awkward or fundamentally wrong?

Comment: It's mostly grammatically correct (using "in order to" would complete it), but essentially no one arranges phrases like that.

Answer (score 0):

The sentence is not understandable without your explanation. The key to the problem is "should". A different modal makes all the difference. Try, "The cubs must be felt loyal by their parents in order to survive their childhood." Whether that's true or not, the new statement can be readily parsed.

Consider the statement, "You must work to get results". The meaning is obvious. Now if I say, "You should work to get results.", that doesn't mean the same thing at all. It seems to say, that you should get your results by working, not by cheating or luck, for example. Modals are tricky. They snuck into English late, via the Teutonic route. Old grammars based on Latin ignored them, and they're still not taught well. "Should" introduces a rule that many other people agree on, "would" a wish by the speaker, "could" a neutral possibility and "must" a law of nature or logic. Although people occasionally use "must" as a stronger form of "should", they know they shouldn't.

Comment: The problem is the “be felt loyal by”. That’s very awkward.  it might be clearer if it was written “must be felt to be loyal by”- clearer, but still pretty awkward.